# string object/array of different variables with their values in php

Tags: php, arrays, variables

There is some Variable in My Code, Now I want to Make a String Of them with there Value as user inputs.
    Variable are as:-
         $A,$B,$C
    and With Inputs
         $A=E,$B=F,$C=D
    Now I want Final Variable Like
        $Param={`A`:`E`,`B`:`F`,`C`:`D`}
    I had Tried This PHP code but Just Not getting How to do With as I want Output Because I want To insert this Variable into the DB table using Insert
Now What is this Called also in technically term . As I am not too much Experiences here.

```html
//First Input as A and It's based ON Post or Get
if(isset($_POST["A"])) 
        {
            $action = $_POST["A"];
        }
        else if(isset($_GET["A"])) 
        {
            $action = $_GET["A"];
        }
        //Input as B and It's based ON POst or Get
            if(isset($_POST["B"])) 
            {
                $action = $_POST["B"];
            }
            else if(isset($_GET["B"])) 
            {
                $action = $_GET["B"];
            }
    $para=array(A:$A,B:$B);
```

Comment: Do you wan't them as an array or as an string separated with `,`and `:`?

Comment: are you trying to make `associative array`?

Comment: Hello sir, I want as an String separated with ,

Comment: Guys .. What is this ...??? Just because I was in hurry and I did some Grammatical error .. You start Decreasing my Points.. Please If you can help than Please help...

Comment: you can just do this `$param='A:'.$A.',B:'.$B.',C:'.$C;`

Comment: Guys .. What is this ...??? Just because I was in hurry and I did some Grammatical error .. You start Decreasing my Points.. Please If you can help than Please help...

Comment: They are not decreasing your points because of your editing the question, they are decreasing because you haven't posted anything else then "Please do this for me", you should post examples of what you have tried and where you got stuck and then we can help you and edit your code, not do all the code for you.

Comment: Ok. Thanks..Now I am Going to Delete This post and Going to reType with the What I had tried...

Comment: Now I have added one  section wich I have tried... -uruloke

Comment: Thanks To All ... :)

Comment: @AKVYAS23 PLEASE MARK THE ANSWER FOR OTHERS HELP.THANKS

Comment: @A-2-A , Simple One Linear Code is $para = json_encode(compact(array('A','B'))); But I can not Mark my answer as right till 2 Days..

Comment: Ok mark after that days, and one thing based on your previous question i gave my answer thanks.

Comment: Can Any one tell be It's Working on them Side or Not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I found It..

```
$URL_PARAMETER = json_encode(compact(array('A','B')));
$URL_PARAMETER = str_replace('"',"`",$URL_PARAMETER);
```

Output Is

{`A`:`E`,`B`:`F`}

https://eval.in/516984

Answer (score 4):

From your output, I think you are talking about [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) variable. So, maybe here is what you want:

```
$Param = json_encode(array(
    'A' => 'E',
    'B' => 'F',
    'C' => 'D'
));

echo $Param; // {"A":"E","B":"F","C":"D"}
```

Comment: I would suggest you add why this solution solves the problem. (Even though I know your method is pretty simple.)

Comment: @uruloke Editted. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @AKVYAS23 because you've editted your question after I've answered.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:?

    `$A='E';
    $B='F';
    $C='D';
    $var = ['A'=> $A, 'B' => $B, 'C' => $C];
    $string = '{';
    foreach ($var as $key => $value){
        $string .= $key.':'.$value.', ';
    }
    $string .= '}';
    echo $string;`